# How to debug difference in command line and work bench out put for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am supposed to create an automated CSV report from our MySQL database. For this purpose I have a standard script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356578)

```
mysql -u $USER -h $DBSERVER  -p $PASS $DB -B -T -e "source myscript.sql" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' >/home/ec2-user/temp.csv
```

Problem is, that the created CSV file has some fields as null or erroneous data. However the query does not seem to be the problem since I inserted the same query verbatim in MySQL work bench and got expected results as well as exported correct CSV through workbench out put export.

My first hunch was SED script could be incorrect but after trying other methods and directly looking at the tab separated file that does not seem to be the case. Following is how I obtained the tab separated file

```
mysql -u $USER -h $DBSERVER  -p $PASS $DB -B -T -e "source myscript.sql" >/home/ec2-user/temp.tsv
```

So the MySQL script itself on command line is not producing correct data. The tab separated file had the same erroneous fields, like the final report.

The report currently has around 6000 rows and around 40 columns, and is growing. The fields which are erroneous are in minority though important and are repeatable with the entire script.

I tried debugging the issue by limiting the number of columns or only extracting the problem rows along with 5 preceding and succeeding those problematic rows using mysql client on terminal, and each time I could not reproduce those erroneous fields and I got the correct results. In fact after my debugging session when I try to create the report file itself on terminal it renders correctly.

However whenever later, I try to create the report file again in one go, the problem surfaces.

What do I want?
Could any body please provide with debugging methodologies to find out why terminal would produce particular fields consistently wrong while MySQL workbench gets them right every time.

I haven't been able to read the direct terminal output of the script since it is large, however the file to which it is piped to, shows those errors.

Since the data belongs to my employer, and only few particular fields are having these errors which I am unable to create a simple replication case, I am not looking for a solution to my problem, but rather ways to find solution to the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you try to use post-processing of the output file. Why you do not prepare the data form you need directly in SQL script (including replace NULLs with any literals or values you need)? SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE allows any data transform and formatting...

Comment: @Akina Because the process running the mysql client does not have the permission to write that file on MySQL server. Also I am going to take this report file and later do bunch of things which I do not want to do on the DB server. However those are not my problems. My problem is why there is a difference between output on workbench and output piped from terminal stream.

Comment: Well, use common SELECT with formatting output data (including add tabs as separators, replace NULLS with zero-length strings, zeroes, etc.) as you need in it. So you'll obtain the format you want and you do not need to use SED. I think you need to edit your `myscript.sql` instead of edit command-line.

Comment: @Akina I agree with you this is duplication of work, however as this post suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/3093708 I would not be having permission to retrieve or create the file, so SED and other things. My problem is not formatting, but raw data coming from stream that is predictable in its corruption of select few fields. The query seems to be proper since workbench handles it well, so question is what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe if you show (or create fiddle) table DDL, example data, query from `myscript.sql` and explain the point (with accuracy to specific byte) of problem, it will be easier to give some suggestion to you.

Comment: @Akina I wish I could provide a specific fiddle. Given that I am myself having trouble able to distill and produce a simple reproducible test case is driving me up the wall, that is why was asking for suggestions on how to debug. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Soham - what about the "export options" of `INTO OUTFILE`??  -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: @Rick James Sorry for the late reply, as you can see in previous replies the outfile is written on the DBA server machine which is on AWS RDS and my remote query will not have the permissions to write on the same.

Comment: What were the "erroneous fields"?